# How can I search my own questions and answers?

Tags: support, search

How about adding an option to search our own questions and answers?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Can already be done. Enter `user: <your_user_id> searchterm` into the search field.

When you are searching **your** posts, you can use `user:me searchterm`.

To search for ***only*** answers or questions, add `is:answer` or `is:question` respectively.